# Problem with a simple recursive function

Tags: functions, recursion

```
f[2 x_] := f[x]
f[1] := 3
f[0] := 0
f[2 x_ + 1] := f[x] + f[x + 1]
a[x_] := f[x]/f[x + 1]
```

Will this work as an recursive function ?
I think there's something wrong with this because every integer will get an output of 3

any help would be appreciated, thank you so much

Comment: From what I'm guessing you're trying to get, I think you'll find `fn = NestList[1/(1 - # + 2 Floor[#]) &, 0, #] &;` most efficient to generate the first *n* terms, e.g. `fn[1000000]` will generate the result from index 0 to 1000000.

Comment: The reason this does not work, is because you can't match an integer to something like `2 x_ + 1`: `MatchQ[7, 2 x_ + 1] (* False *)`. An integer is just an integer: it's not structurally equal to an addition. The pattern matcher is not for matching mathematical patterns like these. Only structural ones. Besides, there's nothing in the pattern `2 x_ + 1` that even limits `x` to be an integer.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps try this

```
f[0] := 0;
f[1] := 3;
f[x_/;EvenQ[x]] := f[x/2];
f[x_/;OddQ[x]] := f[(x-1)/2] + f[(x-1)/2 + 1];
a[x_] := f[x]/f[x + 1];
Table[{i,a[i]},{i,0,6}]
```

with output

```
{{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {2, 1/2}, {3, 2}, {4, 1/3}, {5, 3/2}, {6, 2/3}}
```

Please check this carefully to make certain I haven't made any mistakes

Comment: This is close to just nitpicking, but I'd personally use `?EvenQ` and `?OddQ` instead of `/;EvenQ[x]` etc here. For more complicated pattern matches, the `?` notation seems to be faster typically. In this case, the difference isn't noticeable until `x` values of around 2^1024 on my machine and the recursion limit comes into play first, but I figured it should be noted.

Comment: Thank you so much, I really appreciated your help.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to go to large values of $x$, then some [memoization](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/FunctionsThatRememberValuesTheyHaveFound.html) will speed up your recursion dramatically:

```
f[0] = 0;
f[1] = 3;
f[x_?EvenQ] := f[x] = f[x/2];
f[x_?OddQ] := f[x] = f[(x - 1)/2] + f[(x + 1)/2];
a[x_] := f[x]/f[x + 1]
```

try it out:

```
f[873813] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.000245, 32838}